# Is there a NLP package or function that knows or can find locations from a document?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am using Spacy as well as a bit of custom code to do some natural language processing for work. We want to do something where we can find a where a paper was written by using the locations sited in the paper and was curious if there is a package that could find locations such as countries, cities, states etc? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I believe this is off-topic. See: [help/on-topic].

Comment: @AlexanderCécile You're right, I just flagged it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spacy has named entity recognition (NER). One type of entity that the pre-trained models have is `LOC` for location. There's also `GPE` (geo-political entity) in some of the models. The `en_core_web_sm` I use below has both `LOC` and `GPE`. (Full listing at https://spacy.io/api/annotation#named-entities). See also: https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features#named-entities

It's not going to be perfect out of the box, but it might be useful.

Minimal example:

```py
import spacy          # install cmd: pip3 install spacy --user
import en_core_web_sm # install cmd: python3 -m spacy download en_core_web_sm --user

text='San Fransisco is in California and my friend Frank lives there, close to the bay. He purchased his first house last January.'
NLP = en_core_web_sm.load()
output = NLP(text)
for item in output.ents:
    print(item.label_, item)
```

has this output:

```
GPE San Fransisco
GPE California
PERSON Frank
DATE last January
```

Comment: So would this work without me having to specify a city? Or would I always have to specifically choose what city/state/country I am looking for before running it?

Comment: @greenbur Correct. You do not have to tell it anything since it is using a pre-trained model supplied by spacy (en_core_web_sm). You could train your own model and use yours instead if you find that the spacy one is not reliably finding the locations you wish it to find. I'm not a data scientist but it works by looking at things like sentence structure, parts of speech, punctuation, order of words, etc. I gave it a very simple sentence, but the input `text` could be many paragraphs. In my example, it easily located the two `GPE`s of `San Fransisco` and `California`.

Comment: Great, thanks for the help! I am using it for whole PDFs so hopefully it runs with that as well.

Comment: @greenbur It will work so long as you can get the text out of the PDF. We are using it to scrape websites (and user uploaded docs like PDFs) to do entity extraction (but we're interested in the PERSON and ORG entities). You might want to do some pre-processing to strip out line breaks and other control characters. It will not be perfect (we actually switched to the Stanford NER instead to get better NER results, but that's written in Java not Python) but it's pretty interesting to see what it can do.

Comment: Yep, we already have a full working model that does that so luckily I will hopefully be able to use this! Thank you for the help.